# Setting font color in Fancytree "extraClasses" not applying

Tags: jquery, css, fancytree

I have a tree in my web app that utilises fancytree.  It all works very well except that for some nodes I need to set the font color to red.  I'm using `extraClasses` in my JSON which is all applying perfectly against the appropriate nodes and can be verified using the browser's debugger.

However, while I can easily apply `font-style` and `background-color` CSS attributes, for some reason the font color is not being carried down to the base `span.fancytree-title`.  Instead all nodes are black.

CSS:

```
span.OrgDataTreeNotChecked
{
    background-color: #EFFAFA;
    color: red!important;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

C# generating the relevant extraClasses:

```
if (org.Status == "NotChecked")
    item.extraClasses = "OrgDataTreeNotChecked";
```

In the browser debugger I can see this clearly:

[image: extraClasses node applying as expected]

You can see here that the color has made its way into the attributes for the element:

[image: Color being set]

However, when I highlight the `span.fancytree-title` I can see that the color is being overridden and using black instead.

[image: Color being overridden]

I've tried various things like trying to override the color for those nodes in jQuery in both the `.init` event of the Fancy tree and in the document ready function:

```
$(".OrgDataTreeNotChecked").closest(".fancytree-title").css({ "color": "red" });
```

I even tried the brute force approach of setting the color for *all* `.fancytree-title` elements:

```
$(".fancytree-title").css({ "color": "red" });
```

This also had no effect.  I'm fresh out of ideas.  It just doesn't want to apply the font color and *only* the font color.  Every other attribute works just fine.  Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After considerable effort, I finally solved it.  I wouldn't say it's a perfect solution but it works.

The nodes are not loaded into the DOM until each parent is expanded, so the set contained in `$(".OrgDataTreeNotChecked")` is actually zero length on the `init` event of the tree and obviously in the ready function of the document.

There is, however, an `expand` event on the tree which fires as each node is expanded.  On first load populates the DOM with the child nodes.  So I had to put into the tree the following event handler:

```
expand: function(data) {
    $(".OrgDataTreeNotChecked").children(".fancytree-title").css({ 'color': 'red' });
},
...
```

which then sets everything red.  The reason why I say it isn't a perfect solution is because on each load the text appears black first for just a moment, *then* turns red that is supposed to be red.

It will do for now, but if anyone has a better suggestion, please say so :)

Answer (score 4):

After much trial and error, and using Chrome's "Inspect element" functionality, here's what worked for me:

```
span.OrgDataTreeNotChecked > span.fancytree-title {
    background-color: #EFFAFA;
    color: red!important;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

It seems that the class specified in the extraClasses string gets applied to a fancytree-node span that wraps a fancytree-title span, so "drilling down" with the right angle bracket operator did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

in your css file add this:

```
span.fancytree-node.OrgDataTreeNotChecked > span.fancytree-title,
span.fancytree-node.OrgDataTreeNotChecked > span.fancytree-title:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

your custom class must be applied to li element:

```
<li class="folder expanded">Override CSS style per node
    <ul>
        <li class="OrgDataTreeNotChecked">item</li>
        <li class="folder OrgDataTreeNotChecked">item</li>
    </ul>
```

working example here: http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/sample-theming.html

Answer (score 0):

Try like this way. Hopefully it will fix the problem.

```
span.fancytree-title.OrgDataTreeNotChecked
{
background-color: #EFFAFA;
color:red !important;
font-style: italic;
}
```